# xmltree on Python Element not found error

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have this in my code:

```
r = urlopen(url)
root = ET.fromstring(r.read())
```

This is the XML that is returned:

```
    <registrationcheck>
    <status>Failure</status>
    <errorMsg>This User is already Registered</errorMsg>
</registrationcheck>
```

I need to get the value of status but this code throws an error. WHat am I doing wrong? Can I convert this to JSON?

This is the error I get: error = no element found: line 1, column 0`

Comment: What code throws what error?

Comment: The parsing from string throws this error: error = no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: Please add the complete traceback to the question.

Comment: That's your entire code for parsing? I think we know why there's an error.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly: Please update your question when asked for more information.

Comment: I have update the question to reflect the error.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly which line throwing the error; `ET.fromstring(r.read())`? If so, then how did you inspect the returned XML?

Comment: Since you don't even tell us what `url` is, how can you expect anyone to reproduce the error and help you?

Comment: Works perfectly for me with some `import` statements and `url='http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0MMhzQGA'` added. Please provide a **complete** reproducible test case. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The string you're trying to parse as XML isn't being recognised by your xml library.

What's the output from the following?

```
r = urlopen(url)
data = r.read()
print data[:100]
```